# Memory leak due to large searchresult while querying from LDAP

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

I'm fetching the Userdetails from Ldap to database using datatable.

The processor memory keeps increasing while executing the below code and finally I'm getting 'Memory exception error'.

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domainName, userName, passwd, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
DirectorySearcher dSearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
dSearch.PageSize = 1000;
dSearch.Filter = "(objectClass=*)";
dSearch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
SearchResultCollection src = dSearch.FindAll();
int i = 0;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("mail");
foreach (SearchResult sResultSet in src)
{
 DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
 if (GetProperty(sResultSet, "mail") != "")
 {
   dr["mail"] = GetProperty(sResultSet, "mail").ToString();
 }
 dt.Rows.Add(dr);
 i++;
 if (i == 1000)
 {
  BulkInsertDataTable("TestTable", dt, 2);
  dt.Dispose();
  dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("mail");
  i = 0;
 }
}
```

Can any one please let me know how I can release the memory after each iteration of bulk insert into the database?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You don't need to put a blank line after your every line in your code. Re-format your question. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: Maybe you should check if BulkInsertDataTable leaks memory. Also, your code does not save any results after the last 1000 (if you have 1500, only 1000 will be saved)

Comment: Can you include the code for BulkInsertDataTable? Adding 1000 rows to a data table with a single column should not cause OOM exceptions (I'm thinking the email addresses are no longer than say 100 characters and are not ginormous strings). Additionally, is this the only thread that's running?

Comment: Hi Kha, There are no other threads running.

Comment: I have to insert nearly 10,00,000 records into the database but due to memory leak (Processor memory reached 1.8 GB and stopped the program with OOM exception)  I can able to insert only 4,00,000 records.

Answer (score 0):

your code only dispose the data table once at index 1000. change the line from

```
if (i == 1000)
```

to

```
if ((i % 1000) == 0)

// you should also call BulkInsertDataTable("TestTable", dt, 2); after the foreach loop to insert the last set of data as well
```

Comment: Hi Tien, I have reset the count of i to 0 in the last line inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool BulkInsertDataTable(string tableName, DataTable dataTable, int Mode)
    {
        bool isSuccuss = false;
        try
        {
            if (Mode == 2)
            {
                SqlConnectionObj.Open();
                SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(SqlConnectionObj, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock |             SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers | SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction, null);
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
                SqlConnectionObj.Close();
                isSuccuss = true;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            isSuccuss = false;
            throw ex;
        }

        return isSuccuss;

    }
```